# Refactor an XML to JSON parser class

Tags: object-oriented, ruby, parsing

I used Nokogiri and a piece of ActiveSupport to parse an xml file from a given URL, format the data properly and return a JSON string. The script works as expected, so I'm only wondering if there are ways to make the code better from architecture/naming perspectives.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

$:.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__)

require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'active_support/core_ext'

class Scadenzario
  def initialize(url)
    @url = url
    @events = parse_events
  end

  def xml
    Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse(open(@url))
  end

  def to_json
    @events.to_json
  end

private

  def parse_events
    result = []
    xml.xpath('//item').each do |node|
      result << build_event(node)
    end

    result
  end

  def build_event(node)
    event = Hash.new
    event[:title] = node.at_xpath('title').content
    event[:url] = node.at_xpath('link').content
    event[:start] = format_event_time(node)
    event[:allDay] = false

    event
  end

  def format_event_time(node)
    Time.parse(node.at_xpath('pubDate').content).iso8601
  end
end

puts Scadenzario.new('servizi.seac.it/documenti/rss/rss_scadenzario_annuale.xml').to_json
```

The `parse_events` method can be written like this, but I think it would make the code rather unclear.

```
def parse_events
  xml.xpath('//item').inject([]) do |result, node|
    result << build_event(node)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all seems really nice, I would change few things:

Firstly, your `format_event_time` takes a node object as a param, which is counter-intuitive as I would expect it to accept Time object. I would rename it to 'parse_xml_date` or similar and give it text instead:

```
def parse_xml_time(time_string)
  Time.parse(time_string).iso8601
end
```

The main purpose of this change is to make your `build_event` method the only method specifying the exact xml locations of the required properties, so it is easy to find if those changed.

Secondly,your `build_event` method can be slightly simplified to (including first change):

```
def build_event(node)
  {
    title: node.at_xpath('title').content
    url: node.at_xpath('link').content
    start: parse_xml_time(node.at_xpath('pubDate').content)
    allDay: false
  }
end
```

And finally I would add a small private method `get_param`:

```
def get_xml_param(attribute, node)
  node.at_xpath(attribute).content
end
```

Which would simplify `build_event` to:

```
def build_event(node)
  {
    title: get_xml_param('title', node)
    url: get_xml_param('url', node)
    start: parse_xml_time(get_xml_param('pubTime', node))
    allDay: false
  }
end
```

UPDATE:

Actually there might be few more changes.

Your parse_events method can be written like this:

```
def parse_events
  xml.xpath('//item').map {|node| build_event(node) }
end
```

And I would consider caching an xml method:

```
def xml
  @xml ||= Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse(open(@url))
end
```

Comment: I agree, overall your code looks good though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I really like the xml nodes limitations within build the `build_event` by refactoring the `parse_xml_time`.

Comment: Cool! I've added the `parse_events` with `#inject` above, but `#map` looks much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

@BroiStatse gave a very nice answer. I would like to give my observation about his two last points, and take them even further:

When delegating a `map` to a method, you can use a shortened syntax using `method`:

```
def parse_events
  xml.xpath('//item').map(&method(:build_event))
end
```

Regarding `@url` and `xml`, @BroiStatse suggested caching `@xml`, and I'll say - you don't need to cache `@url`! Once you have used it, you don't need it, so if you load the XML on initialization - you don't need to save `@url` at all:

```
class Scadenzario
  def initialize(url)
    @xml = Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse(open(url))
    @events = parse_events
  end

  attr_reader :xml

  #...
end
```

Comment: Thanks Uri! I didn't know about `&method` until now.